# Chamar um uma função JavaSript a partir de um código html. Obs.: O código JavaScript esta no mesmo arquivo

Tags: javascript, html, html-tags

Preciso chamar funções em html sem um botão, chamando quando uma parte do código em html é executada. com o botão eu já fiz, fica assim :

```
<input type="button" value="Nome do botão" onclick="nomeDaFuncao();" />
```

queria chamar o mesmo evento que esse botão faz, mas só quando uma parte do código fosse executada

Comment: O que queres dizer com "chamar funções em HTML sem um botão"?  podes juntar no JavaScript `nomeDaFuncao();` e isso corre a função certo?

Comment: Será que você está querendo executar algo quando uma parte do HTML for **carregada**? Se for isso, coloque `<script>nomeDaFuncao();</script>` depois do trecho relevante do HTML.

Comment: vlws cara, era isso mesmo ;) Muito obrigado